# MVC 4 Multiple Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm developing a MVC 4 Web Site.

In my site I have a login form in a partial view and I'm rendering it in _layout.cshtml, it uses `LoginModel`.

I also have a contact form, it uses `ContactModel`

When I get to contact form and submit it everything is fine. It went to server side. After it executes I'm returning a view and binding it to `ContactModel`

Which is simply :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(Contact model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        //somecode here
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

It's getting complicated and MVC tries to bind `ContactModel` to login page and gives the following error

> The model item passed into the dictionary is of type
>   'My_Project.Model.ContactModel', but this dictionary requires a model
>   item of type 'My_Project.Models.LoginModel'.

My contact form view :

```
    @model My_Project.Model.ContactModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}

        @using (Html.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "formContact" }))
        {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new {@class = "c2inp1", @placeholder = "Name"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            <br/>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Surname, new {@class = "c2inp2", @placeholder = "Surname"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Surname)
            <br/>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email, new {@class = "c2inp2", @placeholder = "Email"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            <br/>
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "c2inp3", @placeholder = "Message" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message)
            <br/>            
            <input type="image" src="@Url.Content("~/Images/c2img4.png")" alt="" class="c2submit"/>
        }
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

My login form in partial view

```
    @model My_Project.Model.LoginModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}
@if (WebSecurity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    <hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
</hgroup>

    <section id="loginForm">
<h2>Use a local account to log in.</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm(new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Log in Form</legend>
        <ol>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
            </li>
            <li>
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
            </li>
        </ol>
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" />
    </fieldset>

}
</section>


</section>
}
```

In my _layout.cshtml im rendering login form

```
@Html.Partial("_LoginPartial")
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Could you provide some more information such as the view code? Could you also tell us which controller the method is part of?

Comment: Also are the Actions returning a Partial or a full on View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the model you want to pass to the login view in _layout.cshtml view...

Example:

```
@Html.Partial("_yourloginview", new LoginModel())
```

Answer (score 0):

The datatype you pass to the view should correspond with the model you declare within the view.  For instance like this:

```
public ActionResult SomeDerp()
{
    Derp derp = new Derp();
    return View(derp);
}
```

Then the view should have a model declared on top of the SomeDerp-page, maybe something like this:

```
@model Derp
```

Sorry if I'm misunderstanding your question though  :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but im already doing it. That is not my exact problem :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because in your _layout.cshtml you specified the Logon model, so every page now wants this model also.